# Set max UISlider to MPMoviePlayer playableduration

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotificationcenter

How can I set the max value of my UISlider to the playableduration of an `MPMoviePlayer`?

I am creating custom controls for `MPMoviePlayer`.

When I try to use `NSNotificationCenter` with `MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification`, it only returns 0.

I have already tried setting my `MPMoviePlayerController` to `(strong,nonatomic)` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved it. The actual problem was the video I was using on my project does not have a "duration" property when you try to "Get info" in Mac. I used a video which is an MOV captured from my iPad and checked that it has a "duration" property. Hope this helps someone who will come across a similar problem.